# What does Facebook Ads guidelines mean by 'Attribution'?

Tags: facebook, advertising, legal

In [Facebook's Advertising Guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/ad_guidelines.php), you can read the followng:

> **B.    Attribution**
>
> Ads may not assert or imply, directly or indirectly, within the ad
>   content or by targeting, a user's personal characteristics within the
>   following categories:
>
> i. race or ethnic origin;
>
> ii. religion or philosophical belief;
>
> iii. age;
>
> iv. sexual orientation or sexual life;
>
> v. gender identity;
>
> vi. disability or medical condition (including
>   physical or mental health);
>
> vii. financial status or information;
>
> viii. membership in a trade union; ix. criminal record; and x. name.

I own a website that focuses on personality tests/quizzes, e.g. "What animal are you?", "What Disney character would you be?", and I'm wondering if an ad like this:

[image]

would break the guidelines? I feel like any kind of targeted and personalized ad would imply a user's personal characteristic more or less indirectly..

Comment: It sounds to me like they don't want ads that say "Since you broke your arm, you should try this product".   "Are you an optimist or pessimist?" sounds fine from that standpoint, but maybe not "Hey you pessimist!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word 'Attribution' by the Facebook Ads guidelines refers to the language used in your ad copy. Facebook has some good examples of what is acceptable and not, [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/249045061790375).

The example you use would be acceptable since it does not target the attribution categories belonging to any one person (eg. race, religion). I would recommend with every question, running through the list of attribution categories to ensure you're not touching upon any of them.